# How to display 2 month at same page FSCalendar Swift 3

Tags: swift, fscalendar

So i was trying to make the calendar display 2 month at the same time and have vertical scrolling.

[image: it display 2 month at the same tim]

How to do that in Swift?

Comment: Might check GitHub for some frameworks laying around. This one looks pretty easy to drop 2 of them into a `UIViewController` in a `UIStackView` or something like that. https://github.com/WenchaoD/FSCalendar

Comment: Not sure about FSCalendar, but its pretty easy to do with [This One](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using FSCalendar,

```
 calendar.scrollDirection = .vertical
 calendar.pagingEnabled = false
```